# Проблемы с кодировкой Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

При отправки формы русские символы заменяются на знаки вопроса (?).

Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Заменяются где?

Comment: В какой кодировке у вас проект?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev В базу записываются только (?) вместо символов

Comment: @Z.John Проект в UTF-8

Comment: Проверьте кодировку ОС.

Comment: @LogIN попробуйте вывести приходящие данные в консоль, если там неправильные русские символы, то в базу уже неправильные данные попадают

Comment: @LogIN я бы первым делом проверил, что база использует utf-8.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Действительно, база почему-то была создана с кодировкой latin1_swedish_ci. Я, с помощью workbench (бд MySQL), поменял кодировку на utf-8. В базе, таблицах и во всех текстовых полях всех таблиц. Но результат тот же

Comment: @MrFylypenko Хм, в консоли данные  в верной кодировке. Видимо что-то с базой

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос файл конфигурации с бд, ну и какую БД используете.

Comment: В некоторых БД надо указывать кодировку при конфигурации драйвера(например в URL самого подключения). Приведите пример конфиграции `DataSource`, как просили выше